# Not getting my Javascript to work in elementor wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm not getting this HTML/Javascript to work on a website of a customer. I can't figure out why. When I try it in brackets it doesn't work either.

```html
<h2>Vul de massa in en bekijk welk rijbewijs u nodig heeft voor uw aanhangwagen</h2>
<div id="licenceCalculator">
  Toegestaan maximum massa van de aanhangwagen in <b>kg</b><br> (Gewicht + laadvermogen)<br>
  <input type="number" min="0" max="10000" placeholder="" id="licenceCalculatorTrailer" name="massa_aanhangwagen"><br><br> Toegestaan maximum massa van uw voertuig in <b>kg</b><br>
  <input type="number" min="0" max="10000" placeholder="" id="licenceCalculatorCar" name="massa_auto"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn_big btn_green" id="licenceCalculatorSubmit" value="B of BE rijbewijs?"><br><br>
  <span id="licenceCalculatorResult"><a href="https://www.rijksoverheid.nl/onderwerpen/rijbewijs/vraag-en-antwoord/met-welk-rijbewijs-mag-ik-een-motorvoertuig-met-aanhangwagen-besturen" > >> Meer informatie over het benodigde rijbewijs</a></span>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" type='text/javascript'>
  $("#licenceCalculatorSubmit").click(function() {
    var trailer = parseInt($("#licenceCalculatorTrailer").val());
    var car = parseInt($("#licenceCalculatorCar").val());
    var combined = (trailer + car);

    if ($("#licenceCalculatorTrailer").val() && $("#licenceCalculatorCar").val()) {
      if (trailer >= 750) {
        if (combined >= 3500) {
          $("#licenceCalculatorResult").html("U heeft een <b class='red'>BE</b> rijbewijs nodig<br><a href=https://www.rijksoverheid.nl/onderwerpen/rijbewijs/vraag-en-antwoord/met-welk-rijbewijs-mag-ik-een-motorvoertuig-met-aanhangwagen-besturen'>Meer informatie over het benodigde rijbewijs</a>");
        } else {
          $("#licenceCalculatorResult").html("U heeft genoeg aan een <b class='green'>B</b> rijbewijs<br><a href='https://www.rijksoverheid.nl/onderwerpen/rijbewijs/vraag-en-antwoord/met-welk-rijbewijs-mag-ik-een-motorvoertuig-met-aanhangwagen-besturen'>Meer informatie over het benodigde rijbewijs</a>");
        }
      } else {
        $("#licenceCalculatorResult").html("U heeft genoeg aan een <b class='green'>B</b> rijbewijs<br><a href='https://www.rijksoverheid.nl/onderwerpen/rijbewijs/vraag-en-antwoord/met-welk-rijbewijs-mag-ik-een-motorvoertuig-met-aanhangwagen-besturen'>Meer informatie over het benodigde rijbewijs</a>");
      }
    } else {
      $("#licenceCalculatorResult").html("<b class='red'>Beide velden moeten gevuld zijn<br><a href='https://www.rijksoverheid.nl/onderwerpen/rijbewijs/vraag-en-antwoord/met-welk-rijbewijs-mag-ik-een-motorvoertuig-met-aanhangwagen-besturen'>Meer informatie over het benodigde rijbewijs</a></b>");
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: If a `<script>` tag has a `src` attribute on it you cannot put any code in it. You need to put your JS in its own `<script>` tag.

Comment: Thanks! How can I do that exactly?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Examples

Comment: even when I delete src it doesn't work..

Comment: No, don't delete `src`. You need *two separate `<script>` tags*. I'm not sure how I can make it any more clear.

Comment: Ohww, i'm sorry. I didn't understand. Thanks!